# Is it possible to deploy and run your own web application on My Cloud Home Server?

Tags: server, web-applications, cloud, storage

I bought a My Cloud EX2 Server. Usually it is made for storing files, pictures and videos and to access it from everywhere. Therefor you log in and do what you want.

My question is, if somebody can tell my, if i can deploy my own web app, that i developed with django, on this box, that i can access it from anywhere?

I was searching the net and read the documentation of my cloud. But i did not really get a clear answer or a walkthrough.